# Read Properties File in Karaf From Another Bundle

Tags: osgi, karaf

In Karaf, is there a way for a bundle to read a properties file from another bundle?

I have *bundle1*, which contains some classes that *bundle2* uses (*bundle1* exports the package containing those classes in its maven pom via maven-bundle-plugin and *bundle2* imports it). But *bundle2* also needs to use a properties file from *bundle1*. Is there a way that in addition to classes, *bundle2* can access a file from *bundle1*?

From what I've read, one option is to deploy the properties to the karaf etc folder via the features file and then it can be accessed from *bundle2* via blueprint. I would like to avoid that if possible, as *bundle1* is currently not deployed as a feature. So hoping for an alternate approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nicest way is to wrap the access through a class of bundle1. Assume bundle1 contains a class named MyClass. Inside this class you can do this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path). The path is relative to the package of the class.

So a method of this class could return an Inputstream for the properties file or allow access to the actual properties.

In fact you can also access the properties file from bundle2. Simply use MyClass.getResourceAsStream(path) from a class in bundle2. This works as each class is by default loaded by the classloader of the bundle it resides in.

Comment: Hm, I can access the resource file from the bundle in which it resides (bundle1) using your suggestion (sort of... i.e., I had to change it to ...getClass().getClassLoader()...). However, accessing the file from a different bundle (bundle2) still returns null for me.

Comment: You need to use a class from bundle1 to get the classloader. Like MyClass.getClass().getClassLoader() where myclass is in bundle1. You can do this from any class in any bundle and will get the classloader of bundle1.

Comment: OK, I'll try that again. But it does need to be ...getClass().getClassLoader()..., correct? Just want to clarify, as your answer left off the "getClassLoader()" part.

Comment: You can use both but the path is then interpreted differently. The getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream uses an absolute path in the classloader while getClass().getResourceAsStream() is relative to the package if your class.

Comment: Ah, thanks much! That really helps clarify. What also helped is I moved my resource file to src/main/resources. I accidentally had it in src/main/java and it wasn't working. Works now!